# open word document (.docx) without using external app in android

Tags: android, docx

How do I open a .docx file without using external app in android?  I have used Apache POI, OliveDocLibrary, Aspose.words libraries.

1. using Apache POI, I have used required libraries, but still there is an exception while running the app (Exception is - POIFSFileSystem is not there )
2. using OliveDocLibrary, its done, but something like watermark will always be there on the document.
3. using Aspose.words, it is a very heavy library file. If I use this library, heap space exception occurs.

What is the right solution?

Comment: I don't understand OP, Apache POI is not even meant for opening documents in the sense of WYSIWYG rendering.